como pedir un valor para el nodo cuando ya ese valor esta en la lista en c
void comprobar_lista(nodo *p, int *x){
    int num=*x;
    nodo *q;
    q=p;
    end:
    while(q!=NULL){
        if(q->info==num){
            while(q->info==num){
                printf("El elemento %d ya existe en la lista\n");
                printf("Ingrese dato: ");
                scanf("%d", &num);
            }
            if(q->info!=num){
                *x=num;
            }

        }else{
            q=q->liga;
        }
    }
    
}

como puedo hacer para que en la variable *X guarde por referencia el valor cuando ya el valor del nodo no esta en la lista la variable nodo *p de tipo struct con el puntero liga que apunta al siguiente nodo.
        q=creaNodo();
        printf("Ingrese dato: ");
        scanf("%d",&q->info);
        comprobar_lista(p,&q->info);

es para implementarlo en la funcion comprobar_lista(p,&q->info);

al ingresar el 4 me aparece que esta en la lista, pero aùn asì se guarda en la lista y no quiero que se gurade en la lista. Quiero que me pida el valor hasta que diferente a algun valor de la lista
funcion donde lo implementarè

funcion que quiero corregir

así es como quiero que me mande el resultado

